# Swipe listview item detailed activity left or right to slide view in android

Tags: android, listview, gesture

I have a listview, when i click on any item in listview a detailed activity will open.This layout has many widgets like textview, ImageView, share buttons etc. Now I want to slide this detail activity of the item to show the detail view of next item in the list. I am following this http://misha.beshkin.lv/android-swipe-gesture-implementation/ but when i swipe from left to right next view is not displaying just getting a toast message "swipe right". Can any one direct me how to work on this? i am new to android Answers will be appreciated. Following is the code i have used

MainActivity.java(listview page)

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity  {

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList;
ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;
JSONArray posts;


// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://siteurl/posts/pages";

static final String KEY_URL_FOR_MAP = "url_site"; 
 static final String KEY_POSTS = "posts";
 static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_SITEURL = "url";
static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
static final String KEY_CONTENT = "content";
static final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
static final String KEY_ATTACHMENTS = "attachments";
static final String KEY_SLUG = "slug";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumbnail";
static final String KEY_IMAGES = "images";
static final String KEY_URL = "url";



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


  final  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        // Creating JSON Parser instance
                final JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
                try {
                      posts = json.getJSONArray(KEY_POSTS);

        // looping through all song nodes <song>
                for(int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(KEY_ID);
                    String title = c.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                    String siteurl = c.getString(KEY_SITEURL);
                    String date = c.getString(KEY_DATE);
                    String content = c.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
                    // to remove all <P> </p> and <br /> and replace with ""
                     content = content.replace("<br />", "");
                     content = content.replace("<p>", "");
                     content = content.replace("</p>", "");

                    //authornumber is agin  JSON Object
                    JSONObject author = c.getJSONObject(KEY_AUTHOR);
                    String name = author.getString(KEY_NAME);

                    String url = null;
                    String slug = null;
                    try {
                    JSONArray atta = c.getJSONArray("attachments");
                    for(int j = 0; j < atta.length(); j++){
                        JSONObject d = atta.getJSONObject(j);

                        slug = d.getString(KEY_SLUG);

                        JSONObject images = d.getJSONObject(KEY_IMAGES);

                        JSONObject thumbnail = images.getJSONObject(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                        url = thumbnail.getString(KEY_URL);

                    }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }




            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, id);
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
            map.put(KEY_URL_FOR_MAP, siteurl);
            map.put(KEY_DATE, date);
            map.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            map.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
            map.put(KEY_SLUG, slug);
            map.put(KEY_URL, url);



            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
                }   
                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    }



         final ListView  list=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

         // Getting adapter by passing json data ArrayList
            adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);    
             list.setAdapter(adapter);



    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = songsList.get(position);

            Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SampleDesp.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, map.get(KEY_TITLE));
            in.putExtra(KEY_URL_FOR_MAP, map.get(KEY_URL_FOR_MAP));
            in.putExtra(KEY_DATE, map.get(KEY_DATE));                         
            in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, map.get(KEY_NAME));
            in.putExtra(KEY_CONTENT, map.get(KEY_CONTENT));
            in.putExtra(KEY_URL, map.get(KEY_URL));

            startActivity(in);
        }


    });   

 }
   }
```

SampleDesp.java(detailed Activity)

```
public class SampleDesp extends Activity implements SimpleGestureListener {
  private SimpleGestureFilter detector;

 static String title;
 String content; 


    // Your Facebook APP ID
    private static String APP_ID = "308180782571605"; // Replace with your App ID

    // Instance of Facebook Class
    private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
    String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    Button btnFbLogin;
    Button btnPostToWall;

    // JSON node keys
    static final String KEY_URL_FOR_MAP = "url_site"; 
    private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String KEY_SITEURL = "url";
    private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_CONTENT = "content";
    private static final String KEY_URL = "url";
     static final String KEY_SLUG1= "slug";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sampledes);
        detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this);

        final LinearLayout line1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll1);
        LinearLayout line2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll2);

        Button btnShare = (Button)findViewById(R.id.share);

        btnShare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      line1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

      }
    });
        // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();
        final String url1 = in.getStringExtra(KEY_URL);

        ImageView imgv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgdesc);
        ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(url1, imgv);





        // Get JSON values from previous intent

        final String title = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
        final String siteurl = in.getStringExtra(KEY_URL_FOR_MAP);
        String date = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DATE);
        String name = in.getStringExtra(KEY_NAME);
        final String content = in.getStringExtra(KEY_CONTENT);

        // Displaying all values on the screen
        TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
        TextView lblUrl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.url_label);

        TextView lblCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_label);
        TextView lblDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_label);
        TextView lblCont = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content_label);

        lblName.setText(title);
        lblUrl.setText(siteurl);
        lblCost.setText(date);
        lblDesc.setText(name);
        lblCont.setText(content);



        final ImageView email3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.email);


       email3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v){
              //my codes
           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
           Uri data = Uri.parse("mailto:?subject=" + title + "&body=" + content);
           intent.setData(data);
           startActivity(intent);
          }

        });


         final ImageView sms4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sms);
            sms4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
               // Perform action on click

                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setData(Uri.parse(Uri.encode(title)+Uri.encode(content))); 

                shareIntent.setType("text/*");
                shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content);           
                startActivity(shareIntent);
            }
         });

            final ImageView twitter4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.twitter);
            twitter4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
               // Perform action on click
               Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
               i.setData(Uri.parse("http://twitter.com/?status=" + Uri.encode(title) + "" + Uri.encode(siteurl)));
               startActivity(i);

            }
         });

            Button btnFbLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fblogin);
            btnFbLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("Image Button", "button Clicked");
                    loginToFacebook();
                    if (facebook.isSessionValid()) {
                        postToWall();
                    }
                }


            });
    }
     @Override 
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){ 
          this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
         return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me); 
        }
    public void onSwipe(int direction) {
      String str = "";

      switch (direction) {

      case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT : str = "Swipe Right";
                                                      break;
      case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT :  str = "Swipe Left";
                                                     break;
      case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_DOWN :  str = "Swipe Down";
                                                     break;
      case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_UP :    str = "Swipe Up";
                                                     break;

      } 
       Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

     public void onDoubleTap() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Double Tap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     }


                /**
                 * Function to login into facebook
                 * */

                private void loginToFacebook() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     {

                    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
                    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

                    if (access_token != null) {
                        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);





                        Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + facebook.isSessionValid());
                    }

                    if (expires != 0) {
                        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
                    }

                    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
                        facebook.authorize(this,
                                new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                                new DialogListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancel() {
                                        // Function to handle cancel event
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                                        // Function to handle complete event
                                        // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                                        editor.putString("access_token",
                                                facebook.getAccessToken());
                                        editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                                facebook.getAccessExpires());
                                        editor.commit();

                                                                                }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError(DialogError error) {
                                        // Function to handle error

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                                        // Function to handle Facebook errors

                                    }

                                });

                     }else{}
                     }
                     }


                    /**
                     * Function to post to facebook wall
                     * */
                    public void postToWall() {
                         Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("title", "visit us");
                        parameters.putString("link", "http://india.dollardesi.net/ads/metro-logistic-packers-movers/");

                        // post on user's wall.
                        facebook.dialog(this, "feed",parameters, new DialogListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancel() {
                            }

                        });

                    }       



                    /**
                     * Function to Logout user from Facebook
                     * */
                    public void logoutFromFacebook() {
                        mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                                Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);
                                if (Boolean.parseBoolean(response) == true) {
                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            // make Login button visible
                                            btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                                        }

                                    });

                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                                    Object state) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                                    Object state) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
                            }

                        });
                    }

                     }
```

SimpleGestureFilter.java

```
public class SimpleGestureFilter extends SimpleOnGestureListener{

 public final static int SWIPE_UP    = 1;
 public final static int SWIPE_DOWN  = 2;
 public final static int SWIPE_LEFT  = 3;
 public final static int SWIPE_RIGHT = 4;

 public final static int MODE_TRANSPARENT = 0;
 public final static int MODE_SOLID       = 1;
 public final static int MODE_DYNAMIC     = 2;

 private final static int ACTION_FAKE = -13; //just an unlikely number
 private int swipe_Min_Distance = 100;
 private int swipe_Max_Distance = 350;
 private int swipe_Min_Velocity = 100;

 private int mode      = MODE_DYNAMIC;
 private boolean running = true;
 private boolean tapIndicator = false;

 private Activity context;
 private GestureDetector detector;
 private SimpleGestureListener listener;


 public SimpleGestureFilter(Activity context,SimpleGestureListener sgl) {

  this.context = context;
  this.detector = new GestureDetector(context, this);
  this.listener = sgl; 
 }

 public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

   if(!this.running)
  return;  

   boolean result = this.detector.onTouchEvent(event); 

   if(this.mode == MODE_SOLID)
    event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
   else if (this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC) {

     if(event.getAction() == ACTION_FAKE) 
       event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
     else if (result)
       event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL); 
     else if(this.tapIndicator){
      event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
      this.tapIndicator = false;
     }

   }
   //else just do nothing, it's Transparent
 }

 public void setMode(int m){
  this.mode = m;
 }

 public int getMode(){
  return this.mode;
 }

 public void setEnabled(boolean status){
  this.running = status;
 }

 public void setSwipeMaxDistance(int distance){
  this.swipe_Max_Distance = distance;
 }

 public void setSwipeMinDistance(int distance){
  this.swipe_Min_Distance = distance;
 }

 public void setSwipeMinVelocity(int distance){
  this.swipe_Min_Velocity = distance;
 }

 public int getSwipeMaxDistance(){
  return this.swipe_Max_Distance;
 }

 public int getSwipeMinDistance(){
  return this.swipe_Min_Distance;
 }

 public int getSwipeMinVelocity(){
  return this.swipe_Min_Velocity;
 }


 @Override
 public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
   float velocityY) {

  final float xDistance = Math.abs(e1.getX() - e2.getX());
  final float yDistance = Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY());

  if(xDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance || yDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance)
   return false;

  velocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
  velocityY = Math.abs(velocityY);
        boolean result = false;

  if(velocityX > this.swipe_Min_Velocity && xDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance){
   if(e1.getX() > e2.getX()) // right to left
    this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_LEFT);
   else
    this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_RIGHT);

   result = true;
  }
  else if(velocityY > this.swipe_Min_Velocity && yDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance){
   if(e1.getY() > e2.getY()) // bottom to up 
    this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_UP);
   else
    this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_DOWN);

   result = true;
  }

   return result;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
  this.tapIndicator = true;
  return false;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent arg0) {
  this.listener.onDoubleTap();;
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent arg0) {

  if(this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC){        // we owe an ACTION_UP, so we fake an       
     arg0.setAction(ACTION_FAKE);      //action which will be converted to an ACTION_UP later.                                    
     this.context.dispatchTouchEvent(arg0);  
  }   

  return false;
 }


    static interface SimpleGestureListener{
     void onSwipe(int direction);
     void onDoubleTap();
 }

}
```

Comment: because in your onSwipe() method you are just showing toast.

Comment: Whta shall i include inside onswipe() Do you have any sample code @Rahil2952

Answer (score 0):

I think that it may work:

```
    //code from your onItemClick
    HashMap<String, String> map = songsList.get(position);

        Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SampleDesp.class);
        in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, map.get(KEY_TITLE));
        in.putExtra(KEY_URL_FOR_MAP, map.get(KEY_URL_FOR_MAP));
        in.putExtra(KEY_DATE, map.get(KEY_DATE));                         
        in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, map.get(KEY_NAME));
        in.putExtra(KEY_CONTENT, map.get(KEY_CONTENT));
        in.putExtra(KEY_URL, map.get(KEY_URL));
        in.putExtra(LIST_POSITION, position); //passing incremented position

        startActivity(in);
```

And then in your details Activity you will have position of current item of the list that details are displayed on the screen. So now you can increment position, and use the same code (the above one) in your onSwipe(int direction)  method. So if you want to open next item details on your left swipe you do something like this:

```
  public void onSwipe(int direction) {


  switch (direction) {

  case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT : 
                                  break;
  case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT :  
  Intent in = getIntent();
  in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, map.get(KEY_TITLE));
  in.putExtra(KEY_URL_FOR_MAP, map.get(KEY_URL_FOR_MAP));
  in.putExtra(KEY_DATE, map.get(KEY_DATE));                         
  in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, map.get(KEY_NAME));
  in.putExtra(KEY_CONTENT, map.get(KEY_CONTENT));
  in.putExtra(KEY_URL, map.get(KEY_URL));
  in.putExtra(LIST_POSITION, position); //passing clicked position
  finish();
  startActivity(intent);
                                 break;
  case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_DOWN :  
                                 break;
  case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_UP :    
                               break;

  } 

 }
```

But for this code in SWIPE_LEFT when your adding Extras to your intent, you need access to a HashMap from your MainActivity, so you can add a public static method in your MainActivity like:

```
public static String getSongFromHashMap(String key) {
    return songsList.get(key);
}
```

And use this method in SWIPE_LEFT code. I know it's not best solution but it should work :)

Comment: Yeah, I don't tested it. It was supposed to be an idea for you on how to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT : str = "Swipe Left";
     break;
```

to

```
case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT : str = "Swipe Left";
         //Fire intent to your detail activity here
         break;
```

I hope I am closer to your solution.